# Bolding geom_text() and including thousands separator in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following ggplot code.

```
mpg %>%
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = as.character(class))) +
  ggplot2::geom_bar(fill = '#00798c')  +
  ggplot2::geom_text(stat = "count", ggplot2::aes(label = after_stat(count)), position = ggplot2::position_dodge(width = 0.8), vjust = -0.3)
```

How can I make the geom_text() annotations bold and also have a thousands comma separator?

I have been looking at the documentation and not really sure how I can do this?

I tried using `scales::comma(count)` nested inside the `after_stat()` but I got an error. No idea how to bold annotated text after reading the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what's your issue. `scales::comma` works fine for me. To get bold labels add `fontface="bold"`:

Note: As the values are too small I multiplied by 1000 so that we get a thousands separator.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = class)) +
  geom_bar(fill = '#00798c')  +
  geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = after_stat(scales::comma(1000 * count))), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), 
            vjust = -.3, fontface = "bold")
```

[image]